# How to fix snapping with JQuery .draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on project that works with draggable nodes. I'm trying to set up a menu of sorts that the user can drag different nodes from one `div` on the left to another on the right. When I drop the cloned object, it snaps to a seemingly random spot on the second `div`. Is there any way to fix this? My js code is below.

```
$(".initnode").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
});

$("#drop").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable[0].id) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
        }
    }
})
```

EDIT
Here's the html.

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="initnode"></div>
</div>
<div id="drop"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide html?